# Validate dates from DateTimeField are the same

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a form that I am trying to add a clean method to make sure that the dates entered are the same. The form happens to be passing, even when the dates are not the same. I believe the problem is in my clean method, but as it is not passing an error, I am unsure what is causing the issue. I would appreciate any help with this.

```
class LessonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lesson_instrument = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_datetime_start = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute am/pm'}), validators=[validate_date1])
    lesson_datetime_end = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'], required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute am/pm'}), validators=[validate_date2])
    lesson_weekly = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('lesson_instrument', 'lesson_datetime_start', 'lesson_datetime_end', 'lesson_weekly')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        lesson_datetime_start = self.cleaned_data.get("lesson_datetime_start")
        lesson_datetime_end = self.cleaned_data.get("lesson_datetime_end")
        if lesson_datetime_start.date() != lesson_datetime_end.date() and lesson_datetime_start >= lesson_datetime_end:
            raise ValidationError('Dates have to be the same and end time must be later than start time')
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have defined a `clean2()` method. Django is not expecting that method and will never call it.

You need to put all that logic in the same method, namely `clean()`.

Comment: My mistake, I updated the code but now get the error, strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

Comment: Yes. Why are you using `strptime()`? The `lesson_datetime_start` and `end` are already datetimes.

Comment: I want to make sure the date parts of the datetimes match, but not the time parts, those can be different. I thought taking the date portion of datetime using strptime, would allow me to compare just the dates which is what I want

Comment: But `strptime` is for converting *text* to datetimes. They're already datetimes. Just do `lesson_datetime_start.date()`.

Comment: I now have, if lesson_datetime_start.date() != lesson_datetime_end.date() and lesson_datetime_start >= lesson_datetime_end:, but the lesson_datetime_start and lesson_datetime_end are still passing as valid, even when they don't match

Answer (score 0):

In your method `clean()`, try using the variable `cleaned_data` (that you prepared but never actually use) instead of `self.cleaned_data`.

Does that solve your issue?

Comment: My clen() method works, it is my clean2() method that doesn't

Comment: where do you invoke your method `clean2()` ?

Comment: @Shoukran you cannot define arbitrary methods and hope that they get called. If it is not a standard named method that is invoked by one of the parent classes, then your code will never get run.

Comment: I updated my code, but the lesson_datetime_start and lesson_datetime_end are still passing as valid, even when they don't match

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your updated `.clean()` method:

> ```
> def clean(self):
>     cleaned_data = super().clean()
>     lesson_datetime_start = self.cleaned_data.get("lesson_datetime_start")
>     lesson_datetime_end = self.cleaned_data.get("lesson_datetime_end")
>     if lesson_datetime_start.date() != lesson_datetime_end.date() and lesson_datetime_start >= lesson_datetime_end:
>         raise ValidationError('Dates have to be the same and end time must be later than start time')
>     return cleaned_data
> ```

The error will only happen if both conditions are given, which does not seem like the thing you are looking for.

I suggest you split the logic in your `if` statement into 2 separate `if`s:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    lesson_datetime_start = cleaned_data.get("lesson_datetime_start")
    lesson_datetime_end = cleaned_data.get("lesson_datetime_end")
    print('lesson_datetime_start', lesson_datetime_start)
    print('lesson_datetime_end', lesson_datetime_end)

    if lesson_datetime_start.date() != lesson_datetime_end.date():
        raise ValidationError('Dates have to be the same.')

    if lesson_datetime_start >= lesson_datetime_end:
        raise ValidationError('End time must be later than start time.')

    return cleaned_data
```

I think this is closer to what you really intended to do with your validation. Does it work for you?